# Kafka-Connect Cassandra Sink Connector Not Pushing Data To Cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, datastax

I have created Kafka Standalone.properties file to built a connection. The file is placed at home/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties as given below:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/home/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0.jar

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

At second step I have added kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0 file. The file is placed at the path home/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0 , the file is given below:

```
name=users-sink
connector.class=com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=10

loadBalancing.localDc=datacenter1
contactPoints=localhost
port=9042

username=...
password=...

topics=demo
topic.demo.demo.users.mapping=lastname=value.lastname, firstname=value.firstname, email=value.email
```

On my PC Zookeeper is already running and I have also started the Kafka with the following command  `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/connect-standalone.properties`

Now for connecting kafka to sink connector I used the following command `sudo kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/conf/cassandra-sink-standalone.properties &> standalone-mode.log &`

My standalone-mode.log file is empty(I am assuming that means no error because in previous attempts there were errors in this log file which i have resolved ).

Now for uploading the text file through kafka sink connector in cassandra I have used the following command   `cat Desktop/users.txt | kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh   --broker-list localhost:9092   --topic demo   --property "parse.key=true"   --property "key.separator=:"; sleep 10;`

Again there is no error on terminal.
But Now the problem is when I am writing a query to view the data in cassandra database the table is empty:

[image: image showing cqlsh quering showing nothing]

user.txt file is given below:

```
Pruitt:{"lastname":"Pruitt", "firstname":"Allie", "email":"allie@example.com"}
Krause:{"lastname":"Krause", "firstname":"Duncan", "email":"duncan@example.com"}
Chase:{"lastname":"Chase", "firstname":"Juana", "email":"juana@example.com"}
Estrada:{"lastname":"Estrada", "firstname":"Edward", "email":"edward@example.com"}
Singleton:{"lastname":"Singleton", "firstname":"Marie", "email":"Marie@example.com"}
Poole:{"lastname":"Poole", "firstname":"Olivia", "email":"olivia@example.com"}
Marks:{"lastname":"Marks", "firstname":"Timothy", "email":"timothy@example.com"}
Suarez:{"lastname":"Suarez", "firstname":"Claud", "email":"claud@example.com"}
Sloan:{"lastname":"Sloan", "firstname":"Eloy", "email":"eloy@example.com"}
Rodriguez:{"lastname":"Rodriguez", "firstname":"Gale", "email":"gale@example.com"}
Bautista:{"lastname":"Bautista", "firstname":"Constance", "email":"Constance@example.com"}
Mcintyre:{"lastname":"Mcintyre", "firstname":"Donte", "email":"donte@example.com"}
Lang:{"lastname":"Lang", "firstname":"Willa", "email":"willa@example.com"}
Richmond:{"lastname":"Richmond", "firstname":"Dionne", "email":"dionne@example.com"}
```

Comment: You should show your actual users.txt file, also don't use `&> standalone-mode.log &` while debugging so you can immediately see logs

Comment: @OneCricketeer   I have uploaded the users.txt above and after removing &> standalone-mode.log & I received the following error key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter: command not found
kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties: line 11: offset.flush.interval.ms=10000: command not found
kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties: line 13: plugin.path=/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0.jar: No such file or directory........All statements in connect-standalone.properties are not found. I have rechecked all paths are correct.

Comment: The paths aren't the issue. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> started the Kafka with the following command `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/connect-standalone.properties`

You don't start brokers with the Connect properties, you need to use `server.properties`

Plus did you verify Kafka is actually running by creating topics and other tasks mentioned in the official quickstart?

> standalone-mode.log file is empty(I am assuming that means no error

Not necessarily. You're not capturing stderr with that command. e.g `2>&1`

> now connecting kafka to sink connector I used the following command `sudo kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/conf/...`

> received the following error : `command not found kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties`...

Properties files are not executable. You need to run `connect-standalone.sh` which takes those two connect properties files as arguments

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I didn't know that I have to start `server.properties` and `standalone. properties`both side by side.
Yes kafka producer and consumer both are running fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the `cassandra-sink-standalone.properties` file, you need to specify the authentication provider otherwise it will default to `None` which means the connector won't authenticate to the cluster.

Based on what you've posted, it looks like you're using the plain authentication provider so set the following:

```
auth.provider=PLAIN
auth.username=username
auth.password=S0mePa$$word
```

Cheers!

Comment: I have added the above to  `cassandra-sink-standalone.properties ` and restarted the kafka server and executed `sudo kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-1.4.0/conf/cassandra-sink-standalone.properties &> standalone-mode.log ` and `cat Desktop/users.txt | kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh   --broker-list localhost:9092   --topic demo   --property "parse.key=true"   --property "key.separator=:"; sleep 10;` command again and there is no error but the table is  still empty.

Comment: Is Cassandra really listening for clients on `localhost`? What did you set `rpc_address` to?

Comment: I dont know about rpc_address ,kindly tell in which configuration file to check it?

Comment: It's in `conf/cassandra.yaml` of your cluster. Cheers!

Comment: Yes I have found this file and rpc is set to `rpc_address: localhost`.